# How to change Authentication in Visual Studio 2013 during existing project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, visual-studio-2013

I want to change authentication of an existing project but I can't change it. Because, I couldn't find the "Change Authentication" button which exists during new project setup. Please tell me, how can I change authentication of existing project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot change that via a push off a button.
Perhaps compare two sample projects with the existing and desired authentication?!?

Comment: OK, but how can I compare two projects in Visual Studio 2013 to change the desired authentication of existing project?

Comment: I would recommend the tool WinMerge.

You can use it as a standalone tool, to compare files/folders from the File explorer.
I also use that for comparing files in Visual Studio (not for merges).
You can Google for posts how to adjust the settings, so VisualStudio opens WinMerge for a compare (I know, confusing naming).
For example this post: http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/

Comment: @nabiasaroosh :-) Good to hear.